# JQ replace "\n" from inside an encoded field

Tags: json, bash, export-to-csv, jq, gsub

I have by now tried a lot of solutions, but i am afraid my understanding of JQ is laking, I just started trying to use it from 2 days ago.

I got a pretty nice solution to parse my files from Json to Csv, but for 1 little pitfal.

The Json have inside it 1 field that is base64 encoded (.data), which is in itself a encoded Json. Inside this sub-Json, theres a field with text (.text) that have "\n", and when converting, well, the row gets corrupted as the "\n" is translated to actual line breaks in the final file.

This is the command I have now:

```
jq-linux64 -r '["ackId","data","senderPhoneNumber","eventType","eventId","messageId2","postbackData","text","sendTime","project_number","type","event_type","product","messageId","publishTime"], (.receivedMessages[] | [.ackId, .message.data, (.message.data | @base64d | fromjson | .senderPhoneNumber, .eventType, .eventId, .messageId, .postbackData, .text, .sendTime), .message.attributes.project_number, .message.attributes.type, .message.attributes.event_type, .message.attributes.product, .message.messageId,.message.publishTime]) | @csv' <inputfile.txt >outputfile.txt
```

In this command I do the decode, use the "fromjson" and then grab the fields i need from inside it.

The field ".text" is the one that has the linebreaks I wish removed/replaced.

I tried sub and gsub, but was unable to create a valid command line or one that yields the desired output.

Any tips regarding how to replace "\n" from inside the field ",text" ?

Sample Input File:

```
{
  "receivedMessages": [
    {
      "ackId": "xxxxxx",
      "message": {
        "data": "eyJzZW5kZXJQaG9uZU51bWJlciI6ICIrOTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OSIsIm1lc3NhZ2VJZCI6ICIyM2QyM2QyM2QzMmQiLCJzZW5kVGltZSI6ICIyMDIxLTAyLTAyVDIwOjAwOjAwLjAwMDAxIiwidGV4dCI6ICJYWFhYWCBYWFhYWFhYRSwgWFhYWFhYWC8gWHh4eHh4LlxuXG5YeHh4eHh4eHg6XG5cbjEgeHh4eCB4eCB4eHh4ICgyMDAgeHgpXG4yLDUgeHh4eHhcbjEgeHh4eCBcblxuWHh4eHh4IHh4eHh4eCJ9Cg==",
        "attributes": {
          "product": "XXXX",
          "project_number": "XXXXXX",
          "message_type": "TEXT",
          "type": "message"
        },
        "messageId": "234234234234234234",
        "publishTime": "2021-02-02T20:15:22.888Z"
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

When I process this file with the above command, it gives:

```
"ackId","data","senderPhoneNumber","eventType","eventId","messageId2","postbackData","text","sendTime","project_number","type","event_type","product","messageId","publishTime"
"xxxxxx","eyJzZW5kZXJQaG9uZU51bWJlciI6ICIrOTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OSIsIm1lc3NhZ2VJZCI6ICIyM2QyM2QyM2QzMmQiLCJzZW5kVGltZSI6ICIyMDIxLTAyLTAyVDIwOjAwOjAwLjAwMDAxIiwidGV4dCI6ICJYWFhYWCBYWFhYWFhYRSwgWFhYWFhYWC8gWHh4eHh4LlxuXG5YeHh4eHh4eHg6XG5cbjEgeHh4eCB4eCB4eHh4ICgyMDAgeHgpXG4yLDUgeHh4eHhcbjEgeHh4eCBcblxuWHh4eHh4IHh4eHh4eCJ9Cg==","+9999999999999",,,"23d23d23d32d",,"XXXXX XXXXXXXE, XXXXXXX/ Xxxxxx.

Xxxxxxxxx:

1 xxxx xx xxxx (200 xx)
2,5 xxxxx
1 xxxx

Xxxxxx xxxxxx","2021-02-02T20:00:00.00001","XXXXXX","message",,"XXXX","234234234234234234","2021-02-02T20:15:22.888Z"
```

The field ".text" generates line breaks from the encoded "\n", that make 1 row become multiple rows, thus corrupting this row for latter processing.

---Full Answer code as answered by @peak

```
jq-linux64 -r '["ackId","data","senderPhoneNumber","eventType","eventId","messageId2","postbackData","text","sendTime","project_number","type","event_type","product","messageId","publishTime"], (.receivedMessages[] | [.ackId, .message.data, (.message.data|@base64d|fromjson|.senderPhoneNumber,.eventType,.eventId,.messageId,.postbackData,(.text | tostring | gsub("\n"; "|")),.sendTime),.message.attributes.project_number,.message.attributes.type,.message.attributes.event_type,.message.attributes.product,.message.messageId,.message.publishTime]) | @csv' <input.json >output.csv
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Without input, the sample command is far too large. A simpler sample (with corresponding input) would suffice. It's not clear why line breaks pose an issue.

Comment: It would probably be sufficient to show a value of the .text field that illustrates the problem, together with the corresponding value you expect.  It's likely that what you have tried is quite close to what's needed, so please also show an example of that.

Comment: Question updated with sample inputs ans outputs, it gave some work as the data is encoded and it all contains sensible contact data

Comment: So why are you using the -r option?

Comment: "-r" seemed to be sugesed when using @CSV to strip quotes, without it the resulting file is full of escaped quotes that I dont need in the final file. This flat file will be loaded in an database.
Without "-r", the "\n" arent converted to line breaks, but then i have a lot of escaped quotes everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the -r option with the `@csv` filter is intended to (and indeed in this case does) produce valid CSV according to the various CSV standards which allow embedded newlines within quoted string values.

Thus the problem you seem to be facing is that the program which you are using to ingest the CSV does not accept embedded newlines within double-quoted fields.

The simplest workaround may therefore be to "encode" the newline characters in a way that will be acceptable to both you and the other program.

For example, you could encode the newlines as pipe ("|") symbols using the jq filter:

```
gsub("\n"; "|")
```

Assuming "text" is a string-valued field which might contain embedded newlines, you would replace `.text` with

```
(.text | gsub("\n"; "|"))
```

If the value of `.text` might be null, then you will have to decide how you want to handle nulls.  (One possibility would be: `.text | tostring | gsub("\n";"|")`.)

If you want the transformation to apply to all of the string fields, then replace `| @csv` by something like:

```
| map(if type == "string" then gsub("\n"; "|") else . end)
| @csv
```

#### https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

> Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes.

Comment: Can you show how this would look inside a section of my snipet? Sorry for not adding examples, but I did  try to use "gsub" but couldn't find a way for it to be accepted by jq without an error.
Not sure this is the way, but I tried "...   ,(.text |  gsub("\\n"; "|") ), ...   "
jq: error (at <stdin>:14004): null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string

You are right, I dont need proper csv, just a flatfile separatet by some character(s) to be loaded inside a database (oracle11g sqlloader).

Comment: That worked, I found out there was an extra "[...]" in my code after the "fromjson" that was causing problems, when they were removed it worked like a charm, thanks!